# Highcharts: Context Menu Button, onclick function

Tags: javascript, highcharts, onclick

I have a page with several charts, and I add specific options to the exporting context menu for each chart.I need to call somefunction() when any item clicked. absolutely this works but not correctly!

This is the code I am using:

```
HelloWorld = function () {
    var items = [];
    for (var index = 0; index<5; index++) {
        items.push({text: "items "+index, onclick: function() {
            alert(index);
        }});
    }
    return items;
};

buttons: {
  contextButton: {
    menuItems: HelloWorld()
  }
}
```

Here is a fiddle which demonstrates my problem: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MoHSenMHS/xbjjpoh3/1/)

when any items clicked, onclick function alert(5)!
Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) issue.  The problem is here:

```
for (var index = 0; index<5; index++) {
    items.push({text: "items "+index, onclick: function() {
        alert(index);
    }});
}
```

In each iteration, you are setting the value of `onclick` to be a function which alerts `index`. However, the `index` variable within each of these functions are all bound to the one `index` variable declared outside the function. And the value of `index` that they will actually use by the time the function runs is the final value of `index`, which is 5.

In order to fix this, you can use an [IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) wrapper to pass each value of `index` into the anonymous function as a new variable `i` whose value won’t change as `index` changes.

```
for (var index = 0; index<5; index++) {
    items.push({text: "items "+index, onclick: (function(i) {
        return function(){
            alert(i);
        }
    })(index)});
}
```

In other words, the wrapper function executes immediately and returns a new function which behaves like your original function except that it is not bound to the `index` iterator.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/horu7zyp/)